# calculating result across multiple unique rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following MVCE:

```
import pandas as pd

data_in = [
  { 'foo': 'company A', 'bar': 'division 1', 'time': 1, 'diff': 0.99 },
  { 'foo': 'company A', 'bar': 'division 1', 'time': 2, 'diff': 0.95 },
  { 'foo': 'company A', 'bar': 'division 1', 'time': 3, 'diff': 0.94 },
  { 'foo': 'company A', 'bar': 'division 1', 'time': 4, 'diff': 0.90 },
  { 'foo': 'company A', 'bar': 'division 1', 'time': 5, 'diff': 1.01 },

  { 'foo': 'company A', 'bar': 'division 2', 'time': 1, 'diff': 0.91 },
  { 'foo': 'company A', 'bar': 'division 2', 'time': 2, 'diff': 0.92 },
  { 'foo': 'company A', 'bar': 'division 2', 'time': 3, 'diff': 0.93 },
  { 'foo': 'company A', 'bar': 'division 2', 'time': 4, 'diff': 0.94 },
  { 'foo': 'company A', 'bar': 'division 2', 'time': 5, 'diff': 0.95 },

  { 'foo': 'company B', 'bar': 'division 1', 'time': 1, 'diff': 1.01 },
  { 'foo': 'company B', 'bar': 'division 1', 'time': 2, 'diff': 1.08 },
  { 'foo': 'company B', 'bar': 'division 1', 'time': 3, 'diff': 1.21 },
  { 'foo': 'company B', 'bar': 'division 1', 'time': 4, 'diff': 1.22 },
  { 'foo': 'company B', 'bar': 'division 1', 'time': 5, 'diff': 1.18 },

  { 'foo': 'company B', 'bar': 'division 2', 'time': 1, 'diff': 0.81 },
  { 'foo': 'company B', 'bar': 'division 2', 'time': 2, 'diff': 0.82 },
  { 'foo': 'company B', 'bar': 'division 2', 'time': 3, 'diff': 0.88 },
  { 'foo': 'company B', 'bar': 'division 2', 'time': 4, 'diff': 0.87 },
  { 'foo': 'company B', 'bar': 'division 2', 'time': 5, 'diff': 0.87 },
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data_in).set_index(['foo', 'bar', 'time'])
df.sort_index(axis=0, inplace=True)

data_out = []
for name, group in df.groupby(['foo', 'time']):

  print(group) 
# example output
# foo       bar        time
# company B division 1 5     1.18
#           division 2 5     0.87
  result = '?'
  data_out.append({ 'foo': name[0], 'time': name[1], 'result': result })

print('out', data_out)
```

Essentially, I am trying to calculate some result for each company by comparing two divisions, for each time we recorded `diff`.

For the example, I am trying to get a truthy result for when "division 1" performed above a target metric, and when "division 2" performed under the standard target.

One possible solution I've found would be

```
for name, group in df.groupby(['foo', 'time']):
  group = group.reset_index()

  group.loc[(group['bar'] =="division 1") & (group['diff'] > 1.04), 'result'] = True
  group.loc[(group['bar'] =="division 2") & (group['diff'] < 1), 'result'] = True
  group['result'] = group['result'].fillna(False)
  result = group['result'].all(skipna=False)
```

However there could be hundreds of data points for each result, and I feel as though this solution will quickly bloat up the dataframe with hundreds or thousands of additional columns.

I may need to directly compare the `diff` between two rows (ie, if "division 1" is less than "division 2"), which I cannot figure out how to do with the above solution.

Due to the amount of data being processed, I'm concerned primarily about **speed** but also want to avoid any unnecessary memory usage.

What is the best approach to these type of calculations?

Comment: a pandas question with an mvce! *cries happy tears*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Pivoting* could be a nice approach here:

```
df.pivot_table(index=['foo', 'time'], columns='bar', values='diff')
```

gives:

```
bar             division 1  division 2
foo       time                        
company A 1           0.99        0.91
          2           0.95        0.92
          3           0.94        0.93
          4           0.90        0.94
          5           1.01        0.95
company B 1           1.01        0.81
          2           1.08        0.82
          3           1.21        0.88
          4           1.22        0.87
          5           1.18        0.87
```

You now have the values for the divisions in columns which will make comparisons easier.

---

I could also try `unstack`. It is less versatile but far more efficient when it can be used. In my tests, it is more than 7 times faster:

```
df.unstack(1)
                     diff           
bar            division 1 division 2
foo       time                      
company A 1          0.99       0.91
          2          0.95       0.92
          3          0.94       0.93
          4          0.90       0.94
          5          1.01       0.95
company B 1          1.01       0.81
          2          1.08       0.82
          3          1.21       0.88
          4          1.22       0.87
          5          1.18       0.87
```

Comment: Beautiful approach, fits all of my test cases :) Thanks!